# Using the Geometric Series to find where a series converges

Tags: taylor-expansion, geometric-series

I was given a function and told to use the geometric series to find the Taylor series. I was then asked where the series converges. What does this mean? How do I go about solving a problem like this?
The function I was given was:
$$\frac{1}{2-x}$$
However, in general, how should I solve such a problem?

Also, does the Taylor series only help for inputs near zero?
Is that what convergence means - that the Taylor Series works for those numbers? If yes, then does the sine function converge for all real numbers?

Comment: How do you want us to answer if you don't tell us *which* function you are talking about? Concerning your final question, yes, it converges for all real numbers.

Comment: I put in the function

Answer (score 1):

As examples which might help :

- $1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ only converges for $-1 \lt x \lt 1$ and then (as a geometric series) is equal to $\frac1{1-x}$ and is its Taylor series around $x=0$
- $1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$ converges for all real $x$ and  is equal to $e^x$ and is its Taylor series around $x=0$

Your case of $\sin(x) = \frac{x}{1!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots$ is related in many ways to the second example and also converges for all real $x$

*Added:* Your later addition of $\frac{1}{2-x}$ which you might expand to $\frac12 +\frac{x}{2^2} +\frac{x^2}{2^3} +\cdots$ is similar to the first example and only converges when $-2 \lt x \lt 2$

Comment: Since sin(x) and $e^x$ both converge for all real x, that means that the Taylor series is a good approximation for all real x, right?

Comment: @burt - If $x$ is large than you will need a lot of terms for a *good* approximation.  For example $\sin(10) \approx -0.544$ but you need to add up about sixteen terms in the Taylor series to get this to three decimal places.  Meanwhile $\sin(100) \approx -0.506$ but you probably cannot approach this through the Taylor series without much more precision than usual

Comment: I see. But technically it would converge for all x.

Comment: And, if I use the Taylor series centered around 100 I'll get a much quicker approximation?

Comment: @burt: The Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ about $x=100$ involves $\sin(100)$ and $\cos(100)$.  If you want to find an approximation to $\sin(100)$ then it is [perhaps better to do the expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+expansion+of+sin%28x%29+about+x%3D32*pi) about $x=32\pi \approx 100.53$

Comment: should the expansion of $\sin(x)=\frac{x}{1!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}$?

Comment: @burt -yes it should be, and now is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's use your example:   $\dfrac1{2-x}=\dfrac 12\dfrac 1{(1-\frac x2)}=\dfrac 12\sum_{n\ge0}(\dfrac x2)^n$, and converges when $\mid\dfrac x2\mid\lt1$, or $\mid x\mid\lt2$.  This is the Taylor series at $0$.

You can use the same sort of procedure to get the Taylor series at $1$, say:  $\dfrac 1{2-x}=\dfrac 1{1-(x-1)}=\sum_{n\ge0}(x-1)^n$, which converges when $\mid x-1\mid\lt1$.

Comment: But how do you know when it converges?

Comment: The geometric series has partial sum equal to $\dfrac {1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$, which converges to $\dfrac 1{1-x}$, precisely when $\mid x\mid\lt 1$.  Look at the numerator,  and note that $x^{n+1}\to0$.